# maven build for WSo2 artifacts

Tags: maven, build, wso2, artifacts, wso2-integration-studio

I can export below carbon project from the developer studio , but not using maven on command prompt.

There are two modules embedded inside the "carbon" project . One is Config project and another one is registry resource . maven build / mvn package is done from the  car prject level and we are getting below error . As the carbon Project pom has the dependencies as ".xml" . Any pointers here is really appreciated.

Below is project structure.

CArProject -

```
  ConfigProject

   ResoourceProject
```

"com.barclaycardus.svc.account.car:account-service-car:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.barclaycardus.svc.account.car.endpoint:AccountServiceEndpointDev:xml:1.0.0, com.barclaycardus.svc.account.car.sequence:AccountServiceOutSequence:xml:1.0.0, com.barclaycardus.svc.account.car.sequence:AccountServiceInSequence:xml:1.0.0, com.barclaycardus.svc.account.car.proxy-service:AccountProxyService:xml:1.0.0,

Answer (score 0):

When you use maven to build the CAR file for your artifacts, then you need to build the individual artifact project before building the C-App project.

Since this is a tedious task to build each and every project one by one, we have another project type called Maven Multi Module project which acts as a Maven parent project.

So if you want to build everything in a single go, then you need to create a Maven Multi Module project and include all the other projects as modules in this multi module project's pom file.

You can find more information about Maven multi module project from [here](http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/2.0.1/docs/devs_maven_support.html#MavenMultiModule).

So when you build the maven multi module project, it will build all the other projects and the CAR file will be generated in the target folder of the C-App project.