# WSO2ESB - Building a CAR file with Maven

Tags: maven, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 Developer Studio (version 3.7.0), I have created a WSO2 ESB proxy service with a sequence in a "ESB Config Project", this proxy service using a wsdl file located in a "Registry Resources Project". I also created a "Composite Application Project" to generate my .car file (including proxy service, sequence and resources), and deployed this file in my WSO2 ESB installation with success.

Now I am trying to generate (then deploy) the .car file using maven command.

I first tried this solution : https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Deploying+a+CAR+File+with+the+Maven+Plug-In.
When executing command "mvn clean install" on my ESB Config Project, I get this error :

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory ([ESB Config Project Path]\target\capp). 
Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

Indeed, the install goal is configured to be executed in "target/capp" directory :

```
<directory>target/capp</directory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>install</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>mvn</executable>
          <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>clean</argument>
            <argument>install</argument>
            <argument>-Dmaven.test.skip=${maven.test.skip}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
...
```

Then I tried to create a "Maven Multi Module Project", as suggested here : [maven build for WSo2 artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779382/maven-build-for-wso2-artifacts), but I did not found any solution to make it work :

following the steps from this documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS310/Using+Maven+with+Developer+Studio?src=search), I created a "Maven Multi Module Project", and selected my Config, Resources and Composite projects as children. Then I launched the "mvn clean install" command, but still getting the error on ESB Config Project (no POM in target/capp folder).

Actually, I just did not found any information about these errors, and do not understand why the WSO2 documented solution did not work for me.

Does anyone have a suggestion about that ? How does WSO2 Developer Studio generate the .car file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeded in generating a .car file and creating a maven multi module project.

I was trying to create all my maven projects with WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.0, although the sample said to use version 3.2.0. As the WSO2's maven plugins versions change, it now works fine for me, executing maven install with plugin v2.0.4.

And a maven multi module project is finally just a maven project with modules, so it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer for this problem. The exec-maven-plugin version seems to be buggy. The WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.0 add a buggy version (1.2) when creating the project. You just have to change the artifact from:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
```

to:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
```

See this as a complementary information:
[exec-maven-plugin says cannot run specified program, even though it is on the PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393785/exec-maven-plugin-says-cannot-run-specified-program-even-though-it-is-on-the-pa)